# Confusion about the quotient $G/B$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be an affine, complex, reductive algebraic group and $B$ a Borel of $G$. I have seen and understood the proof that $G/B$ is projective. Now, on the other hand, I have made the following reasoning which must be false: Let $U$ be the unipotent radical of $B$ and $T$ a maximal torus of $G$ such that $B=UT$. Then, $\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}\C[G]^U$ is a finitely generated $\C$-algebra. Hence, $G/U$ is an affine variety. On this affine variety, we have an action of the torus $T$, which is affine and reductive. The (categorical) quotient of an affine variety by an affine reductive group is affine, so 
$$\C[(G/U)/\!/T] =\C[G/U]^T=\C[G]^{UT}=\C[G]^B$$
 is finitely generated. This seems to imply that $G$ has an affine, categorical quotient by $B$. But since geometric quotients are also categorical quotients and those are unique, $G/B$ would be affine and that's not true.

Where exactly is the mistake?

Comment: How do you conclude affine from finitely generated algebra of rational functions?

Comment: I thought that I could take the spectrum of this finitely generated algebra and get an affine, categorical quotient: Since those are unique and geometric quotients are categorical, the statement would follow.

Comment: But a scheme having some $R$ as its algebra of rational functions does not mean it is spec of $R$.

Comment: But we are talking about affine varieties, and for those kinds of schemes it's true. Just to be clear, though: You say that $G/U$ is not affine, right?

Comment: Right. But you seem to be concluding that the scheme is affine based on having finitely generated algebra of rational functions, and I don't see how you do that (you do this already for $G/U$).

Comment: Hm. I see what you are saying. My line of argument, however, is more like this: I *can* consider $\operatorname{Spec}(\C[G]^U)$ which *is* an affine variety. It also seems to be a categorical quotient of $G$ by $U$.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by categorical quotient, but this seems to be where the problem is, as $G/U$ is not affine.

Comment: Alright. A [categorical quotient is defined on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_quotient), and I think the problem is that $\operatorname{Spec}(\C[G]^U)$ is a categorical quotient inside the category of *affine* varieties, but it is not a categorical quotient in the category of varieties, or even $\C$-schemes.

Comment: Ahh, that sounds like a likely culprit for this sort of thing. Quotients of general schemes is of course a ridiculously complicated thing (that I am not really very comfortable with).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$G/U$ is not necessarily an affine variety. Take for example $G = SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ and $U = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \ast \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$. Then $G/ U \cong \mathbb C^{2} \setminus 0$ because $U$ is the stabiliser of $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ with respect to the transitive (linear) action of $G$ on $\mathbb{C}^{2} \setminus \{0\}$.

But yes, $\mathbb{C}[G/U] = \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is finitely generated in this case, too.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain Note that this was for $G/U$ which you seemed to assume was affine (rather than $G/B$).

Comment: Okay. I think this will help me to get there. @TobiasKildetoft: You were right, the flaw is in my argument that a quotient is affine just because it has a finitely generated ring of rational functions.